# recursive function to remove all multiples of n in a list

Tags: python

we were asked to make a recursive function that takes in a number, n, and a list and returns a list that doesn’t contain the multiples of n.

```
removeMultiples(2, [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
[3,5,7,9]
```

my attempt is

```
def removeMultiples(x, arr):
    if not arr:
        return []
    else:
        if arr[0] % x == 0:
            del arr[0]
            return removeMultiples(arr[1:], x)
        return x, arr
```

where am i wrong? what should I change?

Comment: After you `del arr[0]`, the rest of the list is `arr`, not `arr[1:]`.

Comment: Quick guess, as it's not clear from your question what exactly is going wrong (you may want to read [ask]): in the `if` you `del` the first array element, and then pass everything from 2nd to last element in the next recursive call.

Comment: why would this need to be recursive, they should give you a problem where recursion actually makes sense to use

Comment: Sometimes your function returns a list, sometimes a tuple. That can't be good…

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use del. Just make a new list. The problem is stated as returning a list, not modifying the old one. You are on the right track using modulus

You can just use list iteration for this,

```
def removeMultiples(x, li):
    return [l for l in li if l % x != 0]
    
print(removeMultiples(3, list(range(14))))
```

Result: [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13]

The comments are correct in that deleting modifies the list so your counter no longer points to the correct element. If you really need to modify the existing list, the best way to is loop through the list backwards, so that you are just removing the last element and the indices of the other elements in the list do not change.

For a recursive function, this has the same result.

```
def removeMultiples(x, li):
    if li:
        return (li[:1] if li[0] % x else []) + removeMultiples(x, li[1:])
    else:
        return []
```

Comment: That's not recursive tho…

Comment: My biggest life challenge is reading the question. It is kind of a ridiculous application of recursion, though.

Comment: recursive function added